# Pass entire contents of a dataframe to a function in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to rework much of my analysis code for signal processing using Dataframes instead of numpy arrays.  However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to pass the entire matrix of a dataframe to a function as an entire unit.

E.g., If I'm computing the common average reference a signal, I have something like:

```
avg = signal.mean(axis=1)
CAR = signal - avg
```

What I'd like to do is pass a pandas array to this function and have it return a dataframe with CAR as the values now.  I'd like to do this without just returning an array and then re-converting it back into a dataframe.

It sounds like when you use df.apply(), it goes row-wise or column-wise, and doesn't put in the whole matrix.  I could alter the code of CAR to make this work, but it seems like it would slow it down quite a bit rather than just using numpy's code to do it all at once.  It probably wouldn't make a big difference for computing the mean, but I foresee this being a problem with other functions in the future that might take longer.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:  To clarify, I'm not just doing this for subtracting the mean, it was just a simple example.  A more realistic example would be linearly filtering the array along axis 0.  I'd like to use the scipy.signal filtfilt function to filter my array.  This is quite easy if I can just pass it a tpts x feats matrix, but right now it seems that the only way to do it is column-wise using "apply"

Comment: Why don't you just pass the DataFrame itself?  It *is* the whole matrix, and you can use methods like `mean` on it just fine.

Comment: I've tried doing that but on some functions this returns an array, not the dataframe.  E.g., I'm trying to do the same thing with a linear filter, but the signal processing functions in scipy seem to expect (and in turn return) arrays..

Comment: I added an answer that may work for you.  Not sure what your comment means exactly though.  You can't change what kind of object other functions *return*, but I'm just saying that in many cases you can pass *in* a DataFrame even if the function expects a numpy array.

Comment: Are you trying to subtract the average from every item in the entire dataframe?  if `signal` is 2D, `avg` will return a 1D frame, correct?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the raw numpy array version of a DataFrame with `df.values`.  However, in many cases you can just pass the DataFrame itself, since it still allows use of the normal numpy API (i.e., it has all the right methods).

Answer (score -1):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html  this will allow you to perform operations on a row (or column, or the entire dataframe).

```
import random
signal=pd.DataFrame([[10*random.random() for _ in range(3)]for _ in range(5)])

def testm(frame, average=0):
    return frame-average  

signal.apply(testm,average=signal.mean(),axis=1)
```

results:

```
signal  

Out[57]: 
      0         1         2
0  5.566445  7.612070  8.554966
1  0.869158  2.382429  6.197272
2  5.933192  3.564527  9.805669
3  9.676292  1.707944  2.731479
4  5.319629  3.348337  6.476631

signal.mean()

Out[59]: 
0    5.472943
1    3.723062
2    6.753203
dtype: float64

signal.apply(testm,average=signal.mean(),axis=1)

Out[58]: 
          0         1         2
0  0.093502  3.889008  1.801763
1 -4.603785 -1.340632 -0.555932
2  0.460249 -0.158534  3.052466
3  4.203349 -2.015117 -4.021724
4 -0.153314 -0.374724 -0.276572
```

This will take the mean of each column, and subtract it from each value in that column.

Comment: That's exactly what he said he doesn't want to do.

Comment: apply also works on entire dataframes.  If you want to subtract 5 (or an avg number) from every item in the data frame, you can do that as well by excluding the axis argument.

Comment: So, it's not that I want to apply a function to every item in the dataframe, it's that I want to pass the entire contents of a dataframe to a function.  For example, the hilbert transform in scipy takes a timepoints x features array, and computes the transform along the first axis.  It is faster to pass a 10,000 by 100 matrix to this function than it is to pass 100 separate 10,000 length columns to this function, which is what would happen if I used "apply".  I'm trying to get around this.