# Getting a function to work on every row of a dataframe (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to pass each cell of a column in a dataframe to a function which then creates a new cell

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667927/pass-entire-contents-of-a-dataframe-to-a-function-in-pandas) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118111/apply-function-to-each-row-of-pandas-dataframe-to-create-two-new-columns?rq=1) but these don't address my issue.

I'm using an [obscure package](https://github.com/woodcrafty/PyETo) so I'll simplify the method using the base packages to ask the question, hopefully the issue will be clear.

**Method:**

Load the data

```
import pandas as pd
import math

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Pass the values of one column to a variable

```
lat = df['A']
```

Create a new column by applying the function to the variable

```
df['sol'] = df.apply(math.sqrt(lat))
```

This gives the error

`TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>`

The error I'm getting using the pyeto package is actually

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-10-b160408e9808>", line 1, in <module>
data['sol_dec'] = data['dayofyear'].apply(pyeto.sol_dec(data['dayofyear']), axis =1)            # Solar declination

File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyeto\fao.py", line 580, in sol_dec
_check_doy(day_of_year)

File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyeto\_check.py", line 36, in check_doy
if not 1 <= doy <= 366:

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 731, in __nonzero__
.format(self.__class__.__name__))

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`
```

I think the issue is the same in both cases, the function will not apply to every cell in the dataframe column, and produces an error.

I want to be able to apply a function to each cell of a dataframe column (i.e. get the square root of each cell in column 'A'). Then store the result of this function as a variable (or another column in the dataframe i.e. have a 'sqrtA' column) , then apply a function to that variable (or column) and so on (i.e. have a new column which is 'sqrtA*100'.

I can't figure out how to do this, and would really appreciate guidance.

**EDIT**

@EdChum 's answer `df['A'].apply(math.sqrt)` or  `data['dayofyear'].apply(pyeto.sol_dec)` (for the package function) helped a lot.

I'm now having issues with another function in the package which takes multiple arguments:

```
sha = pyeto.sunset_hour_angle(lat, sol_dec)
```

This function doesn't apply to a data-frame column, and I have `lat` and `sol_dec` stored as Series variables, but when I try to create a new column in the dataframe using these like so

`data['sha'] = pyeto.sunset_hour_angle(lat, sol_dec)` I get the same error as before...

Attempting to apply the function to multiple columns:

```
data['sha'] = data[['lat'],['sol_dec']].apply(pyeto.sunset_hour_angle)
```

gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-28-7b603745af93>", line 1, in <module>
data['sha'] = data[['lat'],['sol_dec']].apply(pyeto.sunset_hour_angle)

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1969, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_column(key)

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1976, in _getitem_column
return self._get_item_cache(key)

File "C:\Users\pflattery\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1089, in _get_item_cache
res = cache.get(item)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.sqrt`, as this understands arrays:

```
In [86]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['sol'] = np.sqrt(df['A'])
df

Out[86]:
     A   B   C   D       sol
0   52  38   4  71  7.211103
1   59   4  36  15  7.681146
2   37  28  33  73  6.082763
3   58  26   4  96  7.615773
4   31  48  47  78  5.567764
5   43  58  45   4  6.557439
6   69  35  27  39  8.306624
..  ..  ..  ..  ..       ...
98  42   6  40  36  6.480741
99  22  44  11  24  4.690416

[100 rows x 5 columns]
```

To `apply` a function you can do:

```
In [87]:
import math
df['A'].apply(math.sqrt)

Out[87]:
0     7.211103
1     7.681146
2     6.082763
3     7.615773
4     5.567764
5     6.557439
6     8.306624
7     7.483315
8     7.071068
9     9.486833
        ...   
95    3.464102
96    6.855655
97    5.385165
98    6.480741
99    4.690416
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

What you tried was to pass a `Series` to `math.sqrt` but `math.sqrt` doesn't understand non-scalar values hence the error. Also you should avoid using `apply` when a vectorised method exists as this will be faster for a 10K row df:

```
In [90]:
%timeit df['A'].apply(math.sqrt)
%timeit np.sqrt(df['A'])

100 loops, best of 3: 2.15 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 99.7 µs per loop
```

Here you can see that numpy version is ~22x faster here

with respect to what you're trying to do, the following should work:

```
data['dayofyear'].apply(pyeto.sol_dec)
```

**Edit**

to pass multiple columns as args to a method:

```
data.apply(lambda x: pyeto.sunset_hour_angle(x['lat'],x['sol_dec']), axis=1)
```

Comment: Is the `apply(math.sqrt)` meant to be `applymap`, or am I missing something here?

Comment: `applymap` operates on every element in a df `apply` will apply on each column or row for a df or each row for a `Series`

Comment: Thanks, been trying to read the docs of both methods and not quite got it yet, because was constantly mixing up Series and DataFrames.

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for this! `data['dayofyear'].apply(pyeto.sol_dec)` worked. I've hit another issue with the next step, where a custom function from the package takes two arguments - I've edited the post to clarify, the solution you gave doesn't seem to work when the function takes multiple arguments

Comment: Try `data.apply(lambda x: pyeto.sunset_hour_angle(x['lat'],x['sol_dec']), axis=1)`

Comment: Yes this (and the further similar functions taking more arguments based on previous functions) worked! Thanks again.